# HERE Autocomplete: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, here-api

I started to integrate the HERE Android Starter SDK into my application.
According to the documentation (and the runtime error) the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is required to initialize the MapEngine:

```
MapEngine.getInstance().init(..)
```

However I'll only be using the autocomplete functionality.
What is this permission used for in this case?
I'm wondering whether it's used at all if no maps or map images are loaded.

Since this is a quite sensitive permission to ask the users for, I am searching for ways to not require this permission.

Comment: I am only assuming its only for the storage of autocomplate suggestions. Since the api needs to store most suggested / less suggested words to somewhere so when it needs it, it can read from there again, you should grant this permission. Don't be afraid to grant this permission, most of the apps grants it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of investigation, this is what I found out:

The HERE Android Starter SDK is very easy to integrate, but the permissions are mandatory - no matter what features are used.
In the end I decided to integrate the HERE Autosuggest REST API, since that would not require the permissions mentioned.

Information on the REST-API endpoint can be found here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/free-text-search.html